# Is there any reason to not use my IoC as a general Settings Repository?

Tags: inversion-of-control

Suppose that the **ApplicationSettings** class is a general repository of settings that apply to my application such as TimeoutPeriod, DefaultUnitOfMeasure, HistoryWindowSize, etc...  And let's say MyClass makes use of one of those settings - DefaultUnitOfMeasure.

My reading of proper use of Inversion of Control Containers - and please correct me if I'm wrong on this - is that you define the dependencies of a class in its constructor:

```
public class MyClass {
  public MyClass(IDataSource ds, UnitOfMeasure default_uom) {...}
}
```

and then call instantiate your class with something like

```
var mc = IoC.Container.Resolve<MyClass>();
```

Where **IDataSource** has been assigned a concrete implementation and default_uom has been wired up to instantiate from the **ApplicationSettings.DefaultUnitOfMeasure** property.  I've got to wonder however, if all these hoops are really that necessary to jump through.  What trouble am I setting myself up for should I do

```
public class MyClass {
  public MyClass(IDataSource ds) {
    UnitOfMeasure duom = IoC.Container.Resolve<UnitOfMeasure>("default_uom");
  }
}
```

Yes, many of my classes end up with a dependency on **IoC.Container** but that is a dependency that most of my classes will have anyways.  It seems like I maybe should make full use of it as long as the classes are coupled.  Please Agile gurus, tell me where I'm wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> IoC.Container.Resolve("default_uom");

I see this as a classic anti-pattern, where you are using the IoC container as a service locater - the key issues that result are:

- Your application no longer fails-fast if your container is misconfigured (you'll only know about it the first time it tries to resolve that particular service in code, which might not occur except for a specific set of logic/circumstances).
- Harder to test - not impossible of course, but you either have to create a real (and semi-configured) instance of the windsor container for your tests or inject the singleton with a mock of IWindsorContainer - this adds a lot of friction to testing, compared to just being able to pass the mock/stub services directly into your class under test via constructors/properties.
- Harder to maintain this kind of application (configuration isn't centralized in one location)
- Violates a number of other software development principles (DRY, SOC etc.)

The concerning part of your original statement is the implication that most of your classes will have a dependency on your IoC singleton - if they're getting all the services injected in via constructors/dependencies then having some tight coupling to IoC should be the exception to the rule - In general the only time I take a dependency on the container is when I'm doing something tricky i.e. trying to avoid a circular dependency problems, or wish to create components at run-time for some reason, and even then I can often avoid taking a dependency on anything more then a generic IServiceProvider interface, allowing me to swap in a home-bake IoC or service locater implementation if I need to reuse the components in an environment outside of the original project.

Answer (score 4):

I usually don't have many classes depending on my IoC container. I usually try to wrap the IoC stuff in a facade object that I inject into other classes, usually most of my IoC injection is done only in the higher layers of my application though.

If you do things your way you can't test MyClass without creating a IoC configuration for your tests. This will make your tests harder to maintain.

Another problem is that you're going to have powerusers of your software who want to change the configuration editing your IoC config files. This is something I'd want to avoid. You could split up your IoC config into a normal config file and the IoC specific stuff. But then you could just as well use the normal .Net config functionality to read the configuration.

Answer (score 2):

> Yes, many of my classes end up with a dependency on IoC.Container but that is a dependency that most of my classes will have anyways.

I think this is the crux of the issue.  If in fact most of your classes are coupled to the IoC container itself chances are you need to rethink your design.

Generally speaking your app should only refer to the container class directly once during the bootstrapping.  After you have that first hook into the container the rest of the object graph should be entirely managed by the container and all of those objects should be oblivious to the fact that they were created by an IoC container.

Comment: The objects are of course oblivious to how they were created, but if one object needs to create an instance of another it's still going to get an instance of it via the IoC: var c = IoC.Container.Resolve<MyCalculator>() vs. var c = new MyCalculator()

Comment: I would argue that the vast majority of the time you shouldn't be instantiating (or retrieving from the container) any objects inside your classes.  They should be passed in by the container via a constructor arg or setter.  Otherwise you're really just turning the container into a big object cash.

Answer (score 2):

To comment on your specific example:

```
public class MyClass {
    public MyClass(IDataSource ds) {
        UnitOfMeasure duom = IoC.Container.Resolve<UnitOfMeasure>("default_uom");
    }
}
```

This makes it harder to re-use your class.  More specifically it makes it harder to instantiate your class outside of the narrow usage pattern you are confining it to.  One of the most common places this will manifest itself is when trying to test your class.  It's much easier to test that class if the UnitOfMeasure can be passed to the constructor directly.

Also, your choice of name for the UOM instance ("default_uom") implies that the value could be overridden, depending on the usage of the class.  In that case, you would not want to "hard-code" the value in the constructor like that.

Using the constructor injection pattern **does not** make your class dependent on the IoC, just the opposite it gives clients the option to use the IoC or not.